# How to create and configure swap space on an SSD with a running, LUKS-encrypted Linux system?

Tags: memory, ssd, swap, swap-file, swappiness

I have a trusty old ThinkPad R60 with only 3 GB RAM (upgraded from 2 GB) with Linux Mint Debian Edition 4 running on it. I chose LMDE for stability and the desktop environment. The machine is one of my workhorses and, usually having multiple applications/windows/tabs open, is never turned off. This is how the 256 GB SSD is partitioned:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6sAl.png)

As you can see, the drive is encrypted and there is currently no swap space, but due to a chronic RAM shortage I would like to create some (maybe around 3-4 GB, matching RAM capacity) in order address the frequent slowdowns.

Is it possible to freshly create swap on a **running** system and is there a difference between using a swap *partition* and a swap *file*? Does encryption cause any additional issue requiring attention? And is there anything that must be taken into consideration when running an *SSD*?

My layman guess on the last part would be that swap performance will be better with an SSD than with a standard mechanical HDD, but can result in increased wear (more write/erase cycles) when using parts of an SSD as RAM.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach on already running system would be to create a swap file. Example below would create 4 GB one:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile.sys bs=1M count=4096
chmod 600 /swapfile.sys
mkswap /swapfile.sys
swapon /swapfile.sys
sed -i '$ a\/swapfile.sys\tnone\tswap\tsw\t0\t0' /etc/fstab
```

The last line is needed to automatically load it again after reboot.

You are correct as far as SSD/HDD difference is concerned. Swap will indeed perform better on SSD. I wouldn't worry about write/erase cycles as any modern SSD will generally do fine. It's really only issue on either SD or MMC device.

Comment: Sorry, but this solution won't work since **LMDE4 automatically creates a swap file during installation** (without any option to disable it) - i.e. OP already *has* a swap file running! Therefore, a working solution must explain either how to enlarge an already existing & active swap file - or - how to create a new swap file of larger size, "hot-transfer" the contents of the active swap file to the new, empty one, then deactivate the old file and activate the new one. And all this, while the system is running, avoiding loss of data or a system crash. OP is facing a much more complicated issue

Comment: He explicitly said "there is currently no swap space" and image he attached shows no swap partition...

Comment: Yes, and in that you are right. But the image doesn't show the block devices. I'm positive that if OP checks again, `gnome-disks` will show an encrypted swap partition/block device (probably around 2-4 GB). There is no way to install LMDE without it